# How do I return a list of all combinations of column names in SQL, when the output for each of those column names equates to 1 (TRUE)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, combinatorics

For example, here's what a sample dataset looks like in which ID, A, B, C are my column names:

```
ID  A   B   C
L1  1   0   1
L2  1   1   1
L3  0   0   1
```

Here's what I would like the output to show, when the value of that column name equates to 1:

```
ID  Combination
L1  A
L1  C
L1  A,C
L2  A
L2  B
L2  C
L2  A,B
L2  B,C
L2  A,C
L2  A,B,C
```

and so on...

Please note this is just a sample representation of what my dataset looks like, and what I am hoping the output should look like. In my actual dataset, I have over a 100 columns and a few million rows.

Comment: Have you attempted anything???

Comment: Have you considered a `CASE` expression or a lookup and string aggregation.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: @ThomA I have.. there's over 100 columns and potentially it could generate over a million combinations (times how many ever IDs I end up having), so I was wondering if there's an easier way to this dynamically.

Comment: Did you decide to implement bitfields in SQL Server?

Comment: Sounds like you need to unpivot to generate your rows which you could construct with some dynamic SQL if you have a lot of columns. You basically need to unpivot in a CTE and then use that to also union in a separate query to provide distinct combinations and aggregate.

Comment: would combination of 100 of columns potentially generate a REALLY large number, i don't mean millions

Comment: *"there's over 100 columns"* how were we meant to tell that from.yoir question with a sample data of 4 columns..?

Comment: I am new to this community. Obviously, any help is highly appreciated. The reason I have a sample of 4 columns is because I am trying to understand the concept of solving it in the most efficient way possible, rather than trying to confuse people with TMI :) that being said, I just edited my question to give more context. Thanks again!

Comment: The "over 100 columns" constraint might rule out a bit-set solution, but for most other approaches, I think the solution for three or four columns would be expandable to multiple. (The answer below has been amended to include a dynamic SQL approach.) Just be realistic on expected performance. Hopefully your data is sparsely populated with 1's, so that the number of combinations per source row is not too great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY`s to effectively join your starting data with a pair of values - one null value (always present) and and one non-null value (conditionally present). Repeat for each source column and then concatenate those intermediate results.

For that last step, the `CONCAT_WS()` function will nicely handle the combination of null and non-null values while inserting delimiters (commas) in the appropriate places. Add a check to exclude the empty case and you should have the desired results.

```
SELECT DS.ID, Result.Combination
FROM Dataset DS
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(2)) AS Value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A' WHERE DS.A = 1
) A
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(2)) AS Value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B' WHERE DS.B = 1
) B
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(2)) AS Value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C' WHERE DS.C = 1
) C
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', A.Value, B.Value, C.Value) AS Combination
) Result
WHERE Result.Combination > ''
ORDER BY
    DS.ID,
    LEN(Result.Combination),
    Result.Combination
```

Here is a more compact variation:

```
SELECT DS.ID, Result.Combination
FROM Dataset DS
CROSS APPLY (SELECT 'A' AS Val WHERE DS.A = 1 UNION ALL SELECT NULL) A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT 'B' AS Val WHERE DS.B = 1 UNION ALL SELECT NULL) B
CROSS APPLY (SELECT 'C' AS Val WHERE DS.C = 1 UNION ALL SELECT NULL) C
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', A.Val, B.Val, C.Val) AS Combination) Result
WHERE Result.Combination > ''
ORDER BY DS.ID, LEN(Result.Combination), Result.Combination
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BT4rrhoc) for a demo.

Results:

| ID | Combination |
| --- | --- |
| L1 | A |
| L1 | C |
| L1 | A,C |
| L2 | A |
| L2 | B |
| L2 | C |
| L2 | A,B |
| L2 | A,C |
| L2 | B,C |
| L2 | A,B,C |
| L3 | C |

If you have many columns to deal with, you might consider looking into *dynamic SQL* techniques to generate the needed query, which might yield something like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/fP3RKgHZ).

Comment: Great answer, +1 from my side!

Comment: Aside: It might be easier to let [`Concat_WS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) add commas rather than trimming a leading comma, if any. Since it also gracefully handles `null` values you could `select case when DS.A = 1 then 'A' end as Val` and allow the default `null` to fall through. Or shrink the `case` to `iif( DS.A = 1, 'A', NULL )`.

Comment: Thank you @HABO for the excellent suggestion. I have updated the above answer and associated fiddles to use `Concat_WS()` to simplify the comma handling. I didn't see where I could use a `case` expression though, since the null branch needs to always be present to get all of the combinations. Something like (*unsupported syntax*) `CASE WHEN DS.A = 1 THEN ('A' UNION NULL) ELSE NULL END`.

Comment: @TN thank you! this helps. I also tested a similar approach in snowflake and the performance was significantly faster given most of the values are binary.

Answer (score 0):

The following code, available in a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ae3YAH7g), demonstrates one approach. You can use the alternate `select` statements at the end of the common table expression (CTE) to examine the intermediate results and better understand the steps involved.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Samples as Table ( Id VarChar(2), A Int, B Int, C Int );
insert into @Samples ( Id, A, B, C ) values
  ( 'L1', 1, 0, 1 ),
  ( 'L2', 1, 1, 1 ),
  ( 'L3', 0, 0, 1 );
select * from @Samples;

-- Query the data.
with
  ConvertedColumns as (
    -- Convert the non-Id columns from numbers to strings.
    select S.Id, Cols.AC, Cols.BC, Cols.CC
      from @Samples as S
        cross apply ( select
          case when S.A = 1 then 'A' end as AC,
          case when S.B = 1 then 'B' end as BC,
          case when S.C = 1 then 'C' end as CC ) as Cols ),
  Combos as (
    -- Generate all of the interesting combinations of values.
    select CCols.Id, CCols.AC, CCols.BC, CCols.CC
      from ConvertedColumns as CCols
      group by cube ( Id, AC, BC, CC )
      having Id is not NULL ),
  ExtendedCombos as (
    -- Extend the combinations with the comma-separated list of values and column counts.
    select Id, X1.CSL, X2.ZBColumns
      from Combos
      cross apply (
        -- Generate the comma-separated list of column values.
        select Concat_WS( ',', AC, BC, CC ) as CSL ) as X1
      cross apply (
        -- Calculate the zero-based number of columns in the CSL.
        --   Old trick that assumes none of the column values contain commas.
        --   This lets us properly sort the results even if some column values have
        --     varying lengths.
        select Len( X1.CSL ) - Len( Replace( X1.CSL, ',', '' ) ) as ZBColumns ) as X2
      where X1.CSL != '' )
    -- You can use the alternate   select   stamenets to see the intermediate results.
--  select * from ConvertedColumns;
--  select * from Combos;
--  select * from ExtendedCombos;
  select distinct Id, CSL, ZBColumns
    from ExtendedCombos
    order by
      -- Order by the   Id   ...
      Id,
      -- ... and the number of columns in the combination ...
      ZBColumns,
      -- ... and finally the combinations themselves.
      CSL;
```